# Can the cofinality of a $\operatorname{cf}(A)$-directed partially ordered set $A$ be singular?

Tags: cardinals, order-theory

The cofinality of a totally ordered set is always a regular cardinal. On the other hand for any cardinal (regular or singular) $\kappa$ there is a partially ordered set $(A,\leq)$ with $\operatorname{cf}(A,\leq)=\kappa$, for example $(\kappa,=)$.

Assume that $(A,\leq)$ is a partially ordered set of infinite cofinality $\kappa$, and furthermore that $(A,<)$ is $\kappa$-directed, meaning that if $B\subset A$ and $|B|<\kappa$ then there is $a\in A$ such that $b<a$ for all $b\in B$. With this additional assumption, is it still possible that $\kappa$ is a singular cardinal?

*Added question:* If we change the additional assumption of $\kappa$-directedness to the assumption that $(A,\leq)$ is a directed set, is it even then possible that $\operatorname{cf}(A,\leq)$ is a singular cardinal? In other words, is there a directed partially ordered set whose cofinality is a singular cardinal?

Answer (score 3):

Here’s a positive answer to the added question.

Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal. Let $D_0 = \kappa$. Given $D_n$ for some $n \in \omega$, for each $p \in [D_n]^2$ let $E_{n+1} = [D_n]^2 \times \kappa$, $D_{n+1} = D_n \cup E_{n+1}$, and $R_n = \{\langle a,\langle \{a,b\},\alpha \rangle\rangle:\{a,b\} \in [D_n]^2 \land \alpha \in \kappa\}$. Let $D = \bigcup\limits_{n\in\omega} D_n$ and $R = \bigcup\limits_{n\in\omega} R_n$, and let $\preceq$ be the transitive closure of $R$. Clearly $\langle D,\preceq \rangle$ is a directed set, and $|D| = \kappa$. For each $d \in D$ let $\lceil d \rceil = \{a \in D:a \preceq d\}$; clearly $\lceil d \rceil$ is finite.

Now suppose that $A \subseteq D$ with $\omega \le |A|<\kappa$. Let $\lceil A \rceil = \bigcup\limits_{a\in A} \lceil a \rceil$; then $|\lceil A \rceil| = |A| < \kappa = |D|$, so $A$ cannot be cofinal in $D$, and hence $\operatorname{cf}D = \kappa$. This is true even for singular $\kappa$.

**Added:** As LostInMath suggests, this is working too hard: $E_{n+1}$ need only contain one upper bound for each $p \in [D_n]^2$, so we could simply let $E_{n+1} = [D_n]^2$, or avoid $E_{n+1}$ altogether and just let $D_{n+1} = D_n \cup [D_n]^2$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I gave it some thought but failed to see why the modified $D$ is $\kappa$-directed (or even $\aleph_1$-directed). Of course, the upper bound for the subset $A$ is easily found if $A\subset D_n$ for some $n$, but what if $A$ is such that this does not hold. Another thing I wondered is that if it's necessary, at each stage of the construction of the original $D$, to add $\kappa$ points for each pair of points from the previous stages or does adding just one point for each pair suffice.

Comment: Oops! You’re right: the construction handles only the subsets of power $<\kappa$ that live in some $D_n$. Adding just a single point for each pair in the original construction does seem to be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Given an arbitrary infinite cardinal $\kappa$ (which can be regular or singular), here is a simple example of directed poset of cardinality and cofinality $\kappa$.

Take a set $X$ of cardinality $\kappa$ and let $(P,\le)$ be the partially ordered set of finite subsets of $X$, ordered by inclusion.  This is a directed poset of cardinality $\kappa$.

Reusing the notation from the answer by Brian M. Scott, for $d\in P$ let $\lceil d \rceil = \{a \in P:a \le d\}$; clearly $\lceil d \rceil$ is finite.  And for $A\subseteq P$, write $\lceil A \rceil = \bigcup\limits_{a\in A} \lceil a \rceil$.  The set $A$ is cofinal in $P$ exactly when $\lceil A\rceil=P$.

Now suppose $A$ is a subset of $P$ of cardinality less than $\kappa$.  If $A$ is finite, $\lceil A\rceil$ is finite.  And if $A$ is infinite, $|\lceil A \rceil| = |A| < \kappa = |P|$.  So $A$ cannot be cofinal in $P$, and hence $\operatorname{cf}P = \kappa$.